# BIND: Server is blocking on query

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, iptables, bind, ubuntu-14.04

I have a BIND9 server. I can query it and telnet to it from one system. It will not respond at all when this is attempted from another system on the same subnet/VLAN. It behaves as if the packets are being dropped.

With just a simple telnet, I can see, with `tcpdump`, that the packets are being received from this system, but I do not understand why the server never responds. I have already restarted the non-working client system. To minimize interference, I have also disabled that client's local iptables.

For reference, the ACL of the BIND9 server is "any" and iptables is permitting UDP/TCP on 53 from any source. iptables is totally disabled on the non-working client system (by way of UFW).

The server is Ubuntu 16.04 . The working client system is 17.04 . The non-working client system is 14.04 .

Thoughts?

Comment: Check your firewall.

Comment: It's already disabled. Forgot to mention. Updated.

Comment: Not the client system, you need to check the firewall on the server. And any intermediate firewalls between them.

Comment: No firewalls/gateways in-between. I've mentioned that other clients work and that I can see the traffic from the non-working one on the server.

Comment: OK, now _actually_ go check the firewall on the server. The fact that you can see packets with tcpdump doesn't mean they aren't being dropped by the firewall.

Comment: The iptables rules are very simple. Nothing is discriminantly dropping packets on :53 from the one client and permitting them from the others. I'm also logging dropped packets and nothing is getting dropped that's related.

Comment: telnet ist TCP, not UDP - use nslookup to check for answers.

Comment: what packets do you see exactly when run on the server? also increase the log level of the bind server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I had restarted my client system to see if that would help, which it didn't, I was suddenly able to resolve DNS queries against the server. Something must've been out of whack and fell into place on its own.